# GTK:Button onHover effect different on Linux and Windows

Tags: mono, gtk, cairo

I have a GTK button on my GUI app, however, the hover effects are different for both Linux and Windows:

Heres Linux:

[image: http://imgur.com/DKAy6]

Heres Windows:

[image: http://imgur.com/v0FFU]

I did not do anything fancy to the animations, in fact, the animation is default, how can I make it uniform?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your GTK theme. GTK on Windows uses a Windows-like theme by default, so applications look more platform-native.

The accepted practice is to leave the theme up to the user, not the application developer. Some users install special themes because of impaired vision or such like, and they won't appreciate it if you force another theme on them.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I do know a lot about coding, but I'd say that you could hard code that specific theme and/or theme behaviour in your application to prevent it to look improperly on someone else's computer.